# Gradle "compile fileTree" not working when src in module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I use IDEA.
My gradle config is this:

[image: gradle config]

The point is `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`.

And this is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

Then I found `compile fileTree` is not working when java file is in module 'main', but when the java file is under main project, it is working.
How can I get the config valid on module 'main'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh,god!I know why.
NOTE: "dir" is relative to the project root, if you add the dependencies to your android project, 'libs' would need to be in the android/ directory. If you added the dependencies in the core project, 'libs' would need to be in the core/ directory.

So,the libs must in module "main",then is done.